# Python: Pocket API JSON retrieve results always in only on row. What is the solution?

Tags: python, json, dataframe, api, pocket

I am trying **since hours** and a lot of search to get a dataframe from my Pocket API list retrieve.

But my code adds everything up in only one row finally, what is not what I want for sure.

I tried a lot but don't find the error.

My code looks like this:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
from flatten_json import flatten
import collections


import requests
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

# GET request for data in JSON format
parameters = {
     'consumer_key' : '9...9',
     'access_token' : 'c...b',
     'detailType' : 'complete',
     'count' : '10'
     }

response = requests.get('https://getpocket.com/v3/get', params=parameters)

json_string = response.json()
df=pd.json_normalize(json_string)

print(df)
```

The result looks like this:

```
status  complete error  ...     list.3483242700.domain_metadata.greyscale_logo list.3483242700.listen_duration_estimate search_meta.search_type
0       1         1  None  ...  https://logo.clearbit.com/washingtonpost.com?s...                                        0                  normal
```

The source JSON resonse.text looks like this:

```
{"status":1,"complete":1,"list":{"237938806":{"item_id":"237938806","resolved_id":"237938806","given_url":"https:\/\/getpocket.com\/developer\/docs\/v3\/retrieve","given_title":"Pocket Developer Program: Pocket API: Retrieve","favorite":"0"

....

washpost.s3.amazonaws.com\/public\/SMWO67R4BAI6XKWZRFMSE4UAYQ.jpg&w=1440","domain_metadata":{"name":"The Washington Post","logo":"https:\/\/logo.clearbit.com\/washingtonpost.com?size=800","greyscale_logo":"https:\/\/logo.clearbit.com\/washingtonpost.com?size=800&greyscale=true"},"listen_duration_estimate":0}},"error":null,"search_meta":{"search_type":"normal"},"since":1638029019}
```

Comment: Is the idea to make each value under `"list"` be its own row in the dataframe?

Comment: I want each item_id (each article) I added to Pocket to be one row in the DataFrame.

Answer (score 0):

Try `df = pd.json_normalize(json_string["list"].values())`.

From the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html), it seems like `pd.json_normalize` will output one row if you give it a dict, but it will output multiple rows if you give it a list of dicts. Since the JSON data from the API looks like it returns the list of articles as a dictionary mapping the item ID to each item, `json_string["list"].values()` will produce an iterable over all articles in the list.

Comment: It is finally working :) Many thanks to you !

Comment: But I found nothing about having to add 'values()'

Comment: @amarokWPcom I edited my answer to explain why you need `values()` in this case. Let me know if you have any further questions.